# Excel cut and insert based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy, shared

In a shared workbook I'm getting a 1004 error about: "Insert method of range failed."

I have been using the following code for years. (Non shared mode)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim score As Long
Dim scoreRow As Long
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Column >= 2 And Target.Column <= 10 And Target.Row >= 5 And 
  Target.Row <= 9 Then
  Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
  For x = 10 To 19
    score = ws1.Cells(x, 14).Value
    scoreRow = x
      For y = x + 1 To 19
        If ws1.Cells(y, 14).Value > score Then
        score = ws1.Cells(y, 14).Value
        scoreRow = y
  End If 'strange... It looks to stay better after the next code line...
     Next y
 'Next x is missing, too...

If scoreRow <> x Then
  ws1.Cells(scoreRow, 13).Cut
  ws1.Cells(x, 13).Insert
  ws1.Cells(scoreRow, 14).Cut
  ws1.Cells(x, 14).Insert
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help to adjust to a Shared workbook would be great.
The rows 10 to 19 only contain the data i am manupulating (sorting)

Comment: There appear to be missing `Next` and `End If` statements before `End Sub`.

Comment: You should take care of code indentation. The above code could never be working as you say... As stated above `End If` is before `Next y` and `Next x` is completely missing. Please, look to the code as it looks after I edited your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result, you should end up with code like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim ws1         As Worksheet
    Dim x           As Integer
    Dim y           As Integer
    Dim score       As Long
    Dim scoreRow    As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column >= 2 And Target.Column <= 10 And Target.Row >= 5 And Target.Row <= 9 Then
        Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

        For x = 10 To 19
            score = ws1.Cells(x, 14).Value
            scoreRow = x

            For y = x + 1 To 19

                If ws1.Cells(y, 14).Value > score Then
                    score = ws1.Cells(y, 14).Value
                    scoreRow = y
                End If    'strange... It looks to stay better after the next code line...

            Next y
            'Next x is missing, too...

            If scoreRow <> x Then
                ws1.Cells(scoreRow, 13).Cut
                ws1.Cells(x, 13).Insert
                ws1.Cells(scoreRow, 14).Cut
                ws1.Cells(x, 14).Insert
            End If

            ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Next

    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could the code be adjusted to cut and insert the entire row? Rather then cells?

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
If scoreRow <> x Then
    ws1.Rows(scoreRow).Cut
    ws1.Rows(x).Insert
End If
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried that, and only part of the score moves (the team name), while the score itself remains on the same row.

team name is on col 13 and the score is on col 14.